# jQuery slideDown on mobile producing wrong <li> heights, requiring two taps to slideUp

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown, slideup

I'm using jQuery's slideDown function to animate a hidden menu on mobile devices, and I've got an interesting problem. When the menu slides down, the correct spacing between the list items isn't being applied. When I tap on the icon for closing the menu, the spacing corrects, and then a second tap closes the menu. I've never seen this before. Here is the HTML (this is a Drupal site, hence the tons of markup):

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul id="main-menu" class="links inline clearfix">
    <li class="menu-218 first"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-451"><a href="/bio">Bio</a></li>
    <li class="menu-461 active-trail active"><a href="/classes" class="active-trail active">Classes</a></li>
    <li class="menu-464"><a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="menu-476 last"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <img id="nav-arrow-up" src="sites/all/themes/zoakland/assets/nav-arrow-up.png" alt="nav-arrow-up" width="30" height="21" />
</div>
<img id="nav-arrow-down" src="sites/all/themes/zoakland/assets/nav-arrow-down.png" alt="Show navigation menu" width="30" height="21" />
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#nav-arrow-down").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
  $("#navigation").slideDown(400, function() {
     $("#navigation li").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
  });
});
$("#nav-arrow-up").click(function() {                
  $(this).parent().slideUp(400);
  $("#nav-arrow-down").fadeIn(400);
});
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to not use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`, I would instead use css transitions to perform this animation. In my experience css driven animations perform much better and are more dynamic.Here is some [information](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) on css transitions. Although slideup and slidedown are nice quick solutions, I've found their performance is poor in most scenarios.

Heres an example of how to implement a css transition likes this:

CSS:

```
/*inclue transition in the element you want transitioned*/
.element{
width:100px;
height:0px;
opacity:0;
transition:all 1s;
}
/*set custom animation*/
.slidedown{
height:100px;
opacity:1;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.element').addClass('slideDown');
$('.element').removeClass('slideDown');
OR
$('.element').toggleClass('slideDown');
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped, with a couple of tweaks: the transition property on .element needs to be -webkit-transition in order to work on iOS, and the position property needs to be set as well (I used 'relative'). This solution does have one big limitation which is the fixed height for .slidedown. Since my client is using a CMS, the height of the menu div needs to be flexible. I will work on this.

Comment: Okay! Got the box height to be flexible by giving setting max-height on .element to 0 and max-height on .slidedown to 500px, which is taller than the box will ever get.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, another bit of advice is to look into hardware accelerating the transitions to optimize performance. That is if the animations seem jittery or unsmooth.